# iphone add button inside uiviewcontroller

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, tabbar

I have a tab bar controller with 3 tabs. In one of the tabs, the view is a uiviewcontroller. I wish to add a button inside the view so when I click into the tab the button is displayed. How can I do this without the interface builder???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your view controller,

```
 UIButton *aButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
 aButton.frame = CGRectMake(10,20,200,30);
 [aButton setTitle:@"My BUTTON" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
 [aButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPushed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
 [self.view addSubview:aButton];
```

Then you need to implement the buttonPushed method to do whatever the button is supposed to do.

Comment: I did this, my buttonPushed method was just -(void) doNothing because I just wanted to see it drawn on the screen and it didnt draw any button on the screen. In my app delegate i have this:

Comment: make UIViewController with alloc init and then I add it to the tab bar in an array. Nothing is being drawn.

Comment: Also, i put that implementation in the viewDidLoad method. Should it be in the init?

Comment: I put it in the init and it didnt solve anything. Please I know this is easy but what is going on????

Comment: Are you adding your tabbar.view as a subview of the app window?

Comment: yes, i have this:[_window addSubview:[_applicationController view]]; where applicationController is the tabbarcontroller

Comment: OK, so are you seeing tabs?  If so, find the view controller for one of the tabs.  It will be in the viewControllers array that you set in the tabBarController.  Go to THAT view controller's viewDidLoad and add the button code.

Comment: yes i see all 3 tabs, i have icons and titles for them. I placed the button code in that viewDidLoad method. this is what i have in there:-(void)viewDidLoad
{
 //[super viewDidLoad];
 
 UIButton* button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
 button.frame = CGRectMake(10.0f, 430.0f, 300.0f, 30.0f);
 [button setTitle:@"TEST" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
 [button addTarget:self action:@selector(doNothing) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];setView:button];       
 [self.view addSubview:button];
 


}

-(void)doNothing
{
}

Comment: thanks so much for you help. My dumb butt had the button too big and nothing was displaying!

Comment: Well, Butt-Driven-Development has been shown to have some drawbacks.  :-)  Glad it's working.